# The method addObject(String, Object) from the type ModelMap is deprecated?

Tags: spring-mvc

How can I achieve the following in spring mvc 3.2.2?

I get the following error:

The method addObject(String, Object) from the type ModelMap is deprecated?

```
model.addObject("obj", obj);  // obj is pojo
```

Then want to access it within .jsp/jstl view

```
${obj.id}
```

Controller:

```
public class obj {
private String Id;
public void setId(String value) {Id = value;}
public String getId() {
    return Id;
  }
 }
```

View

```
 ${obj.Id} <-- DOES NOT work
 ${obj.getId()} <-- works!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `model.addObject()` with `model.addAttribute("obj", obj)`

Comment: that worked...but for some reason ${obj.Id} was not resolving but ${obj.getId()} does resolve? not sure why...code posted as edit.

Comment: probably because id is private, but `getId()` is public, so it is reachable from outside the owner class